# How to make the findbar appear on bottom again?

Tags: firefox

I'm using Firefox Aurora, and in a recent version the findbar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) started appearing on top of the page instead of where it previously appeared, the bottom. How do I make it appear at the bottom again?

Note I specifically mean the bar that opens when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, *not* the [Search Bar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-bar-easily-choose-your-search-engine). Apparently Mozilla calls the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> bar the 'findbar'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Findbar location is set in the browser itself and can't be adjusted through `about:config` or toolbars.

1. You could install the [FindBar Tweak extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/?src=search) and move the Findbar to the bottom
2. You could install the [Stylish extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) along with [this userstyle](http://userstyles.org/styles/90918/firefox-find-bar-back-on-bottom)

Comment: @user1306322 I hope you don't mind! :) It's a bit confusing that Mozilla uses two terms for the 'find bar' and the 'search bar'. Hopefully including both will help other people find this answer and solve their problems too! I'm glad the extensions worked for you!

Comment: Well, I didn't mind, that's why I accepted it. It's weird though how userstyles can affect browser settings.